# Count cases of number

Tags: list-manipulation, counting

```
h = {140, 140, 175, 160, 175, 125, 120, 105, 15, 90, 150, 175, 85, 110, 
30, 60, 175, 50, 130, 70, 60, 40, 130, 135, 120, 110, 150, 110, 175,
70}
```

I have a list of discrete values and I want to have a list which creates a list with the value given, followed by the number of instances it is in h.
This is my code:

```
a = With[{x = 0}, If[#1 > x, {#1, Count[h, #1]}, 0] & @@@ h]
```

I want

```
a={{140,2},{175,5},...}
```

Comment: Try `Tally` or `Counts`.

Comment: I hadn't found those functions. Thanks